# What type of optimization to perform on my multi-label text classification LSTM model with Keras?

Tags: keras, optimization, deep-learning, nlp, lstm

I'm using Windows 10 machine. Libraries: Keras with Tensorflow 2.0 Embeddings: Glove(100 dimensions).

I am trying to implement an LSTM architecture for multi-label text classification.

I am using different types of fine-tuning to achieve better results but with no luck so far.

The main problem I believe is the difference in class distributions of my dataset but after a lot of tries and errors, I couldn't implement stratified-k-split in Keras.

I am also experimenting with dropout layers, batch sizes, # of layers, learning rates, clip values, validation splits but I get a minimum boost or worst performance sometimes.

For metrics, I use mainly ROC and F1.

I also followed the suggestion from a StackOverflow member who said to delete some of my examples so I can balance my dataset but if I do that I will have a very low number of examples.

1. What would you suggest to me?
2. If someone can provide code based on my implementation for
   stratified-k-split I would be grateful cause I have checked all the
   online resources but can't implement it.
3. Any tips, suggestions will be really helpful.

[Metrics Plots](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ykoJh.png)

[Dataset form+Embedings form+train-test-split form](https://i.stack.imgur.com/042Xw.png)

[Dataset's labels distribution](https://i.stack.imgur.com/kVnTV.png)

[My LSTM implementation](https://i.stack.imgur.com/2FbYA.png)

Comment: Did you try assigning weights to your samples?

Comment: Can you elaborate further on that? I'm not sure I'm following, how can I achieve this?

Comment: Check this article: https://www.tensorflow.org/tutorials/structured_data/imbalanced_data

Comment: I understand the main idea but i cant seem to be able to implement it for a 6 features multi-label classification.